# charCodeAt() inside map function returning original array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following;

```
function rot13(str) { 
 var result = str.split("");
  result.map(function(val) {
    return val.charCodeAt(); 
  });
}
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

when I run this however the returned array is the same as the input array

```
["S", "E", "R", "R", " ", "P", "B", "Q", "R", " ", "P", "N", "Z", "C"]
```

Could someone help me understand why this isn't working?

Comment: add `return` before `result.map(...`

Comment: `result.map` returns a NEW ARRAY .. try `var newArray = result.map......` - oh, yeah, what @RudolfManusadzhian said is more accurate :p

Comment: note `the returned array` ... rot13 returns undefined, so there is no returned array

Comment: Note that because a string is iterable, you can use the new `Array.from()`... `function rot13(str) { 
 return Array.from(str, c => c.charCodeAt(0));
}` A bit more succinct and avoids creating the extra array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.map` creates a new array and does not mutate the original array, so you have to return it explicitly or assign it to a variable:

```
function rot13(str) { 
 var result = str.split("");
 return result.map(function(val) {
   return val.charCodeAt(); 
 });
}
```